# Eloquent method for HasManyThrough

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have been trying to figure out this problem for a good ten hours and am not sure where I am going wrong. I want the items within an order to be displayed based on their relationship to an order.

I have 3 tables I need information from when I am loading a user profile page. On that page I am trying to show previous orders (ie: Order Date) as well as the items that were ordered for each order. Here is a break down of the tables:

**users**

- id

**orders**

- id
- order date
- user_id

**order_items**

- order_id

In my User model I have:

```
public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
    }


public function order_items()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('OrderItem', 'Order');
    }
```

My UserController method looks like so:

```
public function show()
{
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    return View::make('users/show')->with('user', $user);
}
```

In 'users/show.blade.php' I am trying to access the data in these relationships like so:

```
@foreach($user->orders as $order) // this foreach relationship works
    {{ $order->order_date }} 
@endforeach
```

The problem I am having is accessing the items(order_items) for each order. I have done something similar like this on a basic PHP project, but I am trying to learn and use Eloquent. How do I go about making this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is nothing wrong with the hasManyThrough relationship on the User model, in this case it would be better to access the order items through the Order model.

Make sure your Order model has the relationship defined:

```
class Order extends Eloquent {
    public function order_items() {
        return $this->hasMany('OrderItem');
    }
}
```

Now, your view would look something like:

```
@foreach($user->orders as $order)
    {{ $order->order_date }} 
    @foreach($order->order_items as $order_item) // order items for this order
        {{ $order_item->name }} 
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Additional notes:

This isn't required, but to make all this data load a little quicker, you should eager load all the relationships to alleviate the N+1 issue. Read about eager loading [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading).

```
public function show() {
    // eager load the orders and nested order_items records
    $user = User::with('orders.order_items')->find(Auth::user()->id);
    return View::make('users/show')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Additionally, you don't actually need to `find` the user. You already have the user with `Auth::user()`. However, even though you have the user, it'd still be a good idea to eager load the related records:

```
public function show() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    // load the orders and nested order_items records
    $user->load('orders.order_items');
    return View::make('users/show')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are a life saver. I actually had the exact code in the Order model, but the key that got it to work was the eager loading. Trying to call the order_items method in the nested foreach resulted in a Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). 

Thanks again. If I had more of a reputation I would gladly give a +1. Hopefully someone else will find this useful.